# How to resize height of parent to the height of its children?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am working on the GUI of an application that a coworker and I are working on. There is a GUI bug that has been bugging me and I haven't been able to figure out how to fix.

In my GUI there is a gridrow. In one of the columns is a down arrow image that I can press. When you click on the arrow, it will expand additional information. I used the RowDetailsTemplate for the additional information. When you click it again, the additional information will go away. I used a Mouse_Down event to change the visibility of the rows detail from visible to collapsed and vice versa to do this.

The problem is, after I collapsed the additional information, the size of the grid is still expanded as though to fit the additional information. But the additional information's visibility is already set to collapsed so why is my grid not changing back to the original height? How can I resize the height of the datagridrow to the size of its children?

EDIT:

This is my gridrow which originally sets the rowdetails to collapsed:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ReadUnits}" BorderThickness="0" Name="dataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed" HeadersVisibility="Column" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
```

This is the code where the image to click is. The row is inherting this data template. This is were I can creating the Mouse Down event.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="30">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Name="navigationImage" Source=".../expand.png" Width="16" Height="16" MouseDown="navigationImage_MouseDown" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This is where the event is. This will set the visibility of the rowdetails.

```
private void navigationImage_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement frameworkElement = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        Image image = (Image)sender;

        DataGridRow dataGridRow = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(frameworkElement.DataContext);
        if (dataGridRow.DetailsVisibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
        {
            dataGridRow.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            BitmapImage icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri(".../collapse.png"));
            image.Source = icon;
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridRow.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            BitmapImage icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri(".../expand.png"));
            image.Source = icon;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would help if you could post some sample code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @Phil, added some code in question.

Comment: Your code works for me with a simple RowDetailsTemplate.  Try with a simple template and see if that works.  I'm using .NET 4, are you?

Comment: @Phil, Yes I am using .Net 4. I change the template into a simple textblock and the issue is still occuring.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the rowheight and rows you created to host the grid which has "additional information". in your row definition try giving height as "Auto"..

Something like this..

```
<RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
```

Answer (score 0):

So after trying to fix my problem through brute force and using code that looks less than optimal I decided to try and search the web some more and came upon this answer which fixed my problem: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/wpf/thread/a0e7aea8-e9ad-441f-a775-1178aab75fb0

> I seemed to have resolved the issue by setting a completely unrelated setting.
>
> In my child grids I had ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll set to True.
>   Once I set it to False in all the Child Grids it seemed to magically
>   work. Now when I collapse my row details it resizes the containing row
>   appropriately. The one thing that I'd like to see if you can help me
>   with is determining is explain how this fixed the issue.

What I believe happened is when I expanded the dropdown, the scrollviewer was doing its thing but the scrollviewer was just invisible but still there and expanding the parent grid as the child grew bigger. With the scrollviewer disabled, the issues disappeared.